# Best way to diff two Java objects at runtime

Tags: java, diff, comparable, jibx

I have an XML document that I am binding to a POJO with JiBX. Over the course of its lifetime, the document will evolve and new elements will be added and others modified. With each commit, I want to compare the existing document with the new, to-be-saved document and perform an appropriate action (i.e. a notification when a particular field is changed or modified).

It sounds like there are ways to do this with XML, but since I'm already binding the XML and I have it in an object, I'm wondering if there are any existing libraries that essentially can perform a "diff" on two objects of the same class.

My current thought process is to implement something like Java's Comparable<> interface, but instead of returning -1, 0, or 1, it would return the changes somehow. Just wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: What kind of diff you expect if you have object's field of type HashSet? Diff-ing ain't so easy, but if you want ... http://java-object-diff.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Which is why I thought I'd ask before wasting energy rolling my own. My only other data structures are ArrayLists, so this looks really promising!

Comment: Ooof. It's taking almost 8 seconds to do one diff. And even though I'm unmarshalling identical XML docs, it's still coming up as changed. I think it's comparing raw objects rather than the elements in those objects (Strings, ints, longs, etc). But regardless, that's going to be too slow. Since I'm only interested in a subset of elements, I think I'll roll my own. Thanks for the suggestion though!